# VSCode nestjs debugging doesn't hit breakpoint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, debugging, testing, nestjs

I have nestjs monorepo. When i try to run tests in debug mode, it throws some exception. And when i press "continue", nothing happens.

i tried different launch.json configurations, but nothing seemed to work. But when i run tests without :debug, it throws the same exceptions, but when i press "continue" tests get launched and everything works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbfnP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciYje.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af4Zs.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.